# How would I search for emoji using text search in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, full-text-search, emoji

I'm trying to search for emoji in a text indexed collection but it can't handle it.

When I'm searching for the term 'cancer'

```
db.getCollection('my_collection').find( { "$text" : { "$search" : "capricorn" } } )
```

The first document I receive is

[image]

But when I want to ignore documents with the emoji ☾ (which you can see in the first attached image), using the following query

```
db.getCollection('my_collection').find( { "$text" : { "$search" : "capricorn -☾" } } )
```

Still returns the same document as before.

My guts feeling (which I'm not sure at all about) is that the indexed search field is processed behind the scenes (stop words filtering, stemming maybe...) and perhaps it filters out emojis.

So in the end my question is - If there's a processing step for the text index, how would I modify it to keep the emojis. If there isn't a processing step for the text index, what am I missing with my query?

Comment: Collections in mongo can have a [collation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/collation/) that "allows users to specify language-specific rules for string comparison, such as rules for lettercase and accent marks." Depending on the collation, I bet it handles emoji in different ways

Comment: Not sure if/how text index can help here, but you can always do two-stage aggregation. First stage - search the regular text matches with text index, second - filter out emojis with regex.

Comment: The collection I'm working with is quite big, text search is the only feasible way for me for search